# Get Recurrence Pattern from Google Calendar Events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I need help from Google Apps Script experts.

Below you can see my code that honestly I achieved with ChatGPT's help.
I want to fetch the events of a certain calendar into a spreadsheet considering a certain time frame.

I need to get some data to run a calendar analysis. I was already able to accomplish a lot but one of the most difficult things is to get the recurrence pattern information like weekly, montlhy etc. The way I managed to do that was by comparing the difference of days of 2 events in the same series. It worked but there's an issue with that approach, if in my selected time frame there's only 1 event of that series the cadence is not calculated. Also the code is extremely slow.

Can anyone think of a better approach to that?

Thank you so much!

```
function testExportCalendarToSpreadsheet() {
  var calendarId = 'testemail@gmail.com';
  var sheetName = 'Calendar';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.clearContents(); // Clear existing data in the sheet

  var startDate = Browser.inputBox('Enter Start Date (yyyy-mm-dd)');
  var endDate = Browser.inputBox('Enter End Date (yyyy-mm-dd)');

  var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));

  var headers = ['Title', 'Status', 'Duration (minutes)', 'Guest Count', 'Recurrence', 'Cadence', 'Day of the Week', 'Month', 'Quarter', 'Week in Year', 'Period of Day', 'Description', 'Event ID', 'Location', 'Guests', 'Time Zone', 'Start Date', 'End Date'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  var eventObjects = events.map(function(event) {
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(event.getOriginalCalendarId());
    var timeZone = calendar ? calendar.getTimeZone() : ''; // Get the time zone directly from the associated calendar
    return {
      event: event,
      eventId: event.getId(),
      description: event.getDescription(),
      start: event.getStartTime(),
      end: event.getEndTime(),
      duration: calculateDuration(event.getStartTime(), event.getEndTime()),
      location: getLocation(event),
      guests: event.getGuestList().map(function(guest) { return guest.getEmail(); }).join(', '),
      guestCount: event.getGuestList().length,
      timeZone: timeZone,
      recurrence: getRecurrence(event),
      dayOfWeek: getDayOfWeek(event.getStartTime()),
      periodOfDay: getPeriodOfDay(event.getStartTime()),
      quarter: getQuarter(event.getStartTime()),
      month: getMonthName(event.getStartTime().getMonth()),
      week: getWeek(event.getStartTime()),
      status: event.getMyStatus()
    };
  });

  var eventGroups = groupEventsByEventId(eventObjects);

  for (var eventId in eventGroups) {
    var group = eventGroups[eventId];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
      var eventObject = group[i];
      var event = eventObject.event;
      var cadence = calculateCadence(eventObject, group, i);

    var rowData = [
        event.getTitle(),
        event.getMyStatus(),
        eventObject.duration,
        eventObject.guestCount,
        eventObject.recurrence,
          cadence,
        eventObject.dayOfWeek,
        eventObject.month,
        eventObject.quarter,
        eventObject.week,
        eventObject.periodOfDay,
        eventObject.description,
        event.getId(),
        eventObject.location,
        eventObject.guests,
        eventObject.timeZone,
        eventObject.start,
        eventObject.end,
      ];

      sheet.appendRow(rowData);
    }
  }

  // Display success message
  Browser.msgBox('Calendar data exported to spreadsheet successfully!');
}


function groupEventsByEventId(events) {
  var groups = {};
  events.forEach(function(eventObject) {
    var eventId = eventObject.eventId;
    if (!groups[eventId]) {
      groups[eventId] = [];
    }
    groups[eventId].push(eventObject);
  });
  return groups;
}

function calculateCadence(eventObject, group, index) {
  var cadence = '';
  if (eventObject.recurrence === 'Recurring Event' && index > 0) {
    var previousEvent = group[index - 1];
    var cadenceInMillis = eventObject.start.getTime() - previousEvent.start.getTime();
    var cadenceInDays = Math.floor(cadenceInMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    // Define the intervals in days
    const intervals = [
      { label: 'Weekly', days: 7 },
      { label: 'Biweekly', days: 14 },
      { label: 'Triweekly', days: 21 },
      { label: 'Monthly', days: 30 }, // Approximation for a 30-day month
      { label: '6-weeks', days: 42 },
      { label: 'Bimonthly', days: 60 },
      { label: 'Quarterly', days: 90 },
    ];

    // Find the closest interval label
    var closestInterval = intervals.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
      return Math.abs(curr.days - cadenceInDays) < Math.abs(prev.days - cadenceInDays) ? curr : prev;
    });

    cadence = closestInterval.label;
  }
  return cadence;
}



function calculateDuration(start, end) {
  var durationInMillis = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
  var durationInMinutes = Math.floor(durationInMillis / (1000 * 60));
  return durationInMinutes;
}

function getEventType(event) {
  var eventType = 'Unknown';

  if (event.isAllDayEvent()) {
    eventType = 'Appointment (All-Day)';
  } else if (event.isOwnedByMe()) {
    eventType = 'Owned Event';
  } else if (isSharedEvent(event)) {
    eventType = 'Shared Event';
  }

  return eventType;
}

function isSharedEvent(event) {
  var attendees = event.getGuestList();
  for (var i = 0; i < attendees.length; i++) {
    if (attendees[i].getGuestStatus() === CalendarApp.GuestStatus.RESOURCE) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function getRecurrence(event) {
  var recurrence = 'Not recurring';

  if (event.isRecurringEvent()) {
    recurrence = 'Recurring Event';
  }

  return recurrence;
}

function getDayOfWeek(date) {
  var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var dayIndex = date.getDay();
  return daysOfWeek[dayIndex];
}

function getPeriodOfDay(date) {
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if (hour < 12) {
    return 'Morning';
  } else if (hour < 18) {
    return 'Afternoon';
  } else {
    return 'Evening';
  }
}

function getQuarter(date) {
  var month = date.getMonth();
  return Math.floor(month / 3) + 1;
}

function getWeek(date) {
  var onejan = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil(((date - onejan) / 86400000 + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}

function getMonthName(monthIndex) {
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months[monthIndex];
}

function getLocation(event) {
  var location = event.getLocation();

  // Check if it is a physical location or a video conference link
  if (location && location.includes('meet.google')) {
    return 'Online meeting on Google Meet';
  }
  return location;
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the recurrence pattern of repeating events of a Google Calendar.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my questions Tanaike. I am the one who needs to apologize for not being clear in my question.

Comment: The input in the code is the events in my Google calendar. The output is the details of the events like title, duration etc. One specific details which I am having trouble to get is the **recurrence cadence** of the recurrent events (weekly, monthly).
The code bahaves as follows:
1. The user is asked to enter a time frame of the events to be parsed.
2. Some functions get the details and store them in variables.
3. The values are appended in the respective columns of the spreadsheet.

Below I describe my problem.

Comment: One very important details is the recurrence pattern of the meetings. This information is not directly accessible as others like tiltle, start time etc. So the way I thought I could work around that was by calculating the cadence of the recurrent events by the difference of days of 2 meetings of the same series. The problem is that if my user selects a time frame of only 2 weeks for example, and in this time frame there's a monthly event, the recurrence of this event won't be calculated because in the specified time frame there's only 1 event of that event series.

Comment: I hope I was able to be more clear now.

Comment: 以下に、ChatGPTの助けを借りて実現した正直なコードがあります。特定の期間を考慮して、特定のカレンダーのイベントをスプレッドシートに取得したいと考えています。

カレンダー分析を実行するためにいくつかのデータを取得する必要があります。すでに多くを達成できましたが、週次、月次などの繰り返しパターン情報を取得することが最も難しい課題の1つです。私がそれを行う方法は、同じシリーズ内の2つのイベントの日数の違いを比較することでした。これはうまく機能しましたが、このアプローチには問題があります。選択した期間内にそのシリーズのイベントが1つしかない場合、ケイデンスは計算されません。また、コードは非常に遅いです。

この問題に対するより良いアプローチを思いつくことができる方はいますか？

Comment: コードの入力は、私のGoogleカレンダーのイベントです。出力は、タイトル、期間などのイベントの詳細です。私が苦労している特定の詳細は、繰り返しイベントの再発ケイデンス（週次、月次）を取得することです。コードは以下のように動作します：1. ユーザーには解析するイベントの時間枠を入力してもらいます。2. いくつかの関数が詳細を取得し、それらを変数に保存します。3. 値はスプレッドシートの該当する列に追加されます。以下で私の問題を説明します。

Comment: 非常に重要な詳細事項は、会議の繰り返しパターンです。この情報は、タイトルや開始時刻などの他の情報とは異なり、直接アクセスできません。したがって、私がこの問題に対処する方法は、同じシリーズの2つのミーティングの日数の違いによって、繰り返しイベントのケイデンスを計算することでした。しかし、問題は、ユーザーがたとえば2週間の期間を選択し、この期間内に月次イベントがある場合、このイベントの再発は計算されないということです。指定された期間内にそのイベントシリーズのイベントが1つしかないためです。